# Export webpack module for another application

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-style-loader

If I have a webpack module, how can I configure it so that it can be used by another application? There are two parts to this :

What would be the correct way to host this module for access to all other applications? Private npm repository seems like an option. Anything else?

How can I pass CLI arguments to the config file such that it'd know which asset to pick up or require depending on what argument is passed? For example, passing "red" would pick up the red stylesheet file.

Answer (score 1):

I bundle NPM modules using Webpack thanks to its convenient `output.libraryTarget` option. With this, Webpack will wrap your code in whatever format it supports. (AMD, UMD, CommonJS, CommonJS2, root/global)

You can see the available options [here in the source code](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/LibraryTemplatePlugin.js)